# Is it impossible to use Select inside a projection in a union?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

```
    return await result.Select(student => new MarkSheetsStudentByIdDto
    {
        Id = student.RegId,
        FullName = student.FullName,
        AnnualMarkSheets = student.TermOne
        .Select(x => new MarkSheetDto
        {
            ...
            Comments = student.Comments.Where(x => x.StudentId.Equals(student.RegId)).Select(x => x.CommentText).ToList()
        }).Union(student.TermTwo
        .Select(x => new MarkSheetDto
        {
            ...
            Comments = student.Comments.Where(x => x.StudentId.Equals(student.RegId)).Select(x => x.CommentText).ToList()
        })).ToList()
    }).FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
```

For the above example code snippet, I am getting this error at runtime.

> Unable to translate set operation after client projection has been
> applied. consider moving the set operation before the last 'select'
> call.

If I remove the comments it will not happen. Can anyone please guide me on how to solve this?

Comment: It is very complex query for LINQ translator. Two eager loading queries with `Union` and actually you need `Concat`.  You can do client side post processing I can show how to do that if you don't mind.

Comment: Yes please if you can. But I tried Concat() method to get all the comments list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do client-side post processing. EF Core can translate Eager Loading queries if it is simple. `Union/Concat` adds additional complexity.

```cs
var rawResult = await result.Select(student => new 
    {
        Id = student.RegId,
        FullName = student.FullName,
        TermsOne = student.TermOne
          .Select(x => new MarkSheetDto
          {
              ...
              Comments = student.Comments.Where(x => x.StudentId.Equals(student.RegId)).Select(x => x.CommentText).ToList()
          }).ToList(),
        TermsTwo = student.TermTwo
          .Select(x => new MarkSheetDto
          {
              ...
              Comments = student.Comments.Where(x => x.StudentId.Equals(student.RegId)).Select(x => x.CommentText).ToList()
          }).ToList()
    }).FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);

if (rawResult == null)
  return null;

return new MarkSheetsStudentByIdDto
{
    Id = rawResult.Id,
    FullName = rawResult.FullName,
    AnnualMarkSheets = rawResult.TermsOne.Concat(rawResult.TermsTwo).ToList()
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind effort. This worked for me. But I am curious about why Union() method cannot handle the Select() method inside a projection.

Comment: And moreover, the same error I mentioned in the question was thrown when I used Concat() instead of Union() in the code snippet I showed in the question. Is this not a functionality that we can achieve through LINQ queries?

Comment: Problem that `student.TermOne.Select` and  `Comments` inside (collection) are Eager Loading queries, it is very special LINQ translator processing because SQL do not have such term. LINQ translator uses main query to filter out detail records and then combine them on the client side. Ideally translator has to do the same client-side evaluation as I did, but it is another efforts for implementation.